# XSLT to copy only certain nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, siblings

I have an XML input who looks like this:

```
 <root>
      <NFe>
        <infNFe>
          <wanted_node_1>
            <stuff>1111111</stuff>
          </wanted_node_1>

          <wanted_node_2>
            <stuff>2222222</stuff>
          </wanted_node_2>

          <unwanted_node_1>
            <stuff>aa</stuff>
          </unwanted_node_1>

         ...

          <unwanted_node_25>
            <stuff>zz</stuff>
          </unwanted_node_25>

        </infNFe>
      </NFe>

    </root>
```

I want the output to be an XML file with just the 2 siblings "**wanted nodes**" as such

```
<root>
  <NFe>
    <infNFe>

      <wanted_node_1>
        <stuff>1111111</stuff>
      </wanted_node_1>

      <wanted_node_2>
        <stuff>2222222</stuff>
      </wanted_node_2>

    </infNFe>
  </NFe>
</root>
```

I do NOT want to copy the other 25 siblings "**unwanted_nodes**". I am new to XSL and the code I wrote deals with it by creating a 25-element-long list of exceptions containing all the unwanted siblings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"
              indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="wanted_node_1 | wanted_node_2 ">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--exceptions list-->
  <xsl:template match="unwanted_node_1 | unwanted_node_2 | unwanted_node_3 | ... | unwanted_node25 "/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My problem is that the currently 25 long list of unwanted siblings could increase, forcing me to keep updating the "exceptions list", an obvious bad approach.  Since my two "**wanted nodes**" will always be the same , I would like my XSLT to copy ONLY the 2 wanted nodes skipping all other siblings, using such a logic:

**if** match = wanted_node_1 **or** match = wanted_node_2 **then**
    *do stuff*
**else**
    *skipp unwanted node*
**end if**

I tried dealing with the exceptions list by using things like

```
  <xsl:template match="not(self::wanted_node_1) and not(self::wanted_node_2)>
```

with many permutations of bracket positions, curly brackets etc. but always getting an error message. How then to limit the XML output to just the 2 wanted nodes without creating a 25 long list of unwanted siblings?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<xsl:template match="infNFe/*[not(self::wanted_node_1 | self::wanted_node_2)]"/>`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="infNFe">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="wanted_node_1 | wanted_node_2"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```